# Mark a Magento order as complete programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I'm trying to mark a "Processing" order as Complete when I get a certain response back from a third party service. I've got everything set up for this, but the only problem is that orders are staying in the Processing state.

I'm generating an invoice (I don't think I need this though, as each item is marked as "invoiced" in the Magento backend) and a shipment like so:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')... (etc)
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($quantities);
$shipment->register();
$shipment->setOrder($order);
$shipment->save();

$invoice = $order->prepareInvoice($quantities);
$invoice->register();
$invoice->setOrder($order);
$invoice->save();
```

This doesn't seem to be doing it though - I get no errors back from this code, but the order remains as processing. In the backend I can still see the "Ship" button at the top of the order, and each item is in the "invoiced" state.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at [this article](http://snowcore.net/magento-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0) (in Russian).

Here is the code from the article:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

if (!$order->getId()) {
    return false;
}

if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
    return false;
}

$savedQtys = array();
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($savedQtys);
if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
    return false;
}
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
$invoice->register();

$invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

$transactionSave->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, the code in the article did the trick after I changed to to a shipment rather than an invoice.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is now broken.

Comment: Would be really nice to have an updated link. archive.org still has a version of the link in case anyone is interested. http://web.archive.org/web/20110414102634/http://snowcore.net/magento-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0.  Use google chrome to get a translation.

Comment: @Mike domain will be available in few days, so you can check later

Comment: @gregdev can you share your solution? (shipment rather than invoice)

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
$order->setStateUnprotected('complete',
    'complete',
    'Order marked as complete automatically',
    false);
```

This method is in `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` (in v1.6.1)

```
938:    public function setStateUnprotected($state, $status = false, $comment = '', $isCustomerNotified = null)
```

In Magento 1.7.0.0 this method has been removed. Try this instead:

```
    $order->setData('state', "complete");
    $order->setStatus("complete");
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order marked as complete automatically.', false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This didn't seem to have any effect in Magento 1.4

Comment: Threw error, `Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object` in 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing this that way:

```
$order->setState('complete', true, $this->__('Your Order History Message Here.'))
      ->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This brought up the error "The Order State "complete" must not be set manually."

Answer (score 1):

**Code for processing order programmatically.**
Can be put on success event or cron

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

$order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);

$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order is complete', false);
$history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);

$order->save();
```

Comment: Why are you setting state and status to the same value?

Comment: @MarcusWolschon : For better understanding take a look of "sales_order_status" table . Status is a representation of state and based on it , status label is displayed.

Comment: The names of the shop-specific status codes (and their translated labels) are usually different from the fixed Magento state values. A status is assigned to a state and one status may be assinged as the default status for a Magento state.
So the question remains. Why set status and state to the same value. The status is Shop-specific and should not come from a Magento constant for a state.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will automatically mark an order as complete if:

- Payment has been made.
- An invoice exists.
- A shipment exists.

If you cannot do that, try to create a custom 'state' and set that. In the meantime, to set the order to processing, try this:

```
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
 $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();
```

Should work without errors. Tested in Magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: But you can not create a custom state.
Just a custom status and assign one or multiple status values to a state.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed the end users to see completed in the order grid, but the order state really made no difference.   So I did just went to

System->Order Status
Create a new Status called Completed (note the d so it's easy to differentiate)
Assign that status to the state Processing/pending, whatever.

This worked for our client -- but wouldn't work if you heavily depend on order state (Different than order status).